# configure TimeZone

Tags: 12.04, c++, time

I have two computers with Ubuntu 12.04, both configured with location Santiago. However the time zones are different (blue bar under map)

[image]
[image]

This generate problems when program in c++ and ask for the time difference of localTime with Gmtime.

```
time_t t = time(0);
struct tm* now = localtime(&t);
struct tm* now2 = gmtime(&t);
```

Is it possible that this behavior is due to a decree Supreme No. 106 of the Ministry of the interior of Chile, which has changed the time at summer throughout the year?

How can configure the timezone of PC1 to look like PC2 ?

PD: in both computers i run the commands

```
sudo ntpdate -u ntp.ubuntu.com
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

also check :

- the Time in Bios (both set with UTC TIME)
- the `/etc/default/rcS` with `UTC=yes`
- configure dualboot (in one PC) to Windows use UTC TIME;
- the difference (c++ code) from now and now2 after the call to gmtime;
- check the flag `tm_isdst`, with value 0;

  PD2 : the timezone in PC2 is the correct TimeZone

Comment: Your screenshots say once Santiago and once Santiago de Chile. I doubt it is related to summertime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem! It was not updated the tzdata in one computer.
For update the tzdata execute in console

```
sudo apt-get install tzdata tzdata-java
```

With this command, the time configuration when executed

```
zdump -v America/Santiago | grep 2015
```

should print these

```
America/Santiago  Sun Apr 26 02:59:59 2015 UTC = Sat Apr 25 23:59:59 2015 CLST isdst=1 gmtoff=-10800
America/Santiago  Sun Apr 26 03:00:00 2015 UTC = Sun Apr 26 00:00:00 2015 CLT isdst=0 gmtoff=-10800
```